# Conditional ref qualifier

Tags: c++11, ref-qualifier

I have CRTP-like hierarchy where derived classes may be implemented a bit differently and for one class some methods are allowed to call on rvalue references but for another class this would be undesired:

```
template <class TDerived>
struct Base {
    TDerived& foo() {
        // Body
        return static_cast<TDerived&>(*this);
    }
};

struct Derived1: public Base<Derived1> {};
struct Derived2: public Base<Derived2> {};

int main() {
    // Should not compile:
    // Derived1().foo();

    // Should compile:
    Derived2().foo();
    return 0;
}
```

So to prohibit calling `foo()` on rvalue references one can add ref-qualifier like this:

`TDerived& foo() & {...}`

But I'm wondering is there any simple way to add such ref-qualifier conditionally without duplicating `foo()` method (and adding a bit of SFINAE-like code)?